# Login credentials

Tags: vmware-esx, vmware-vcenter

Is it possible to find login credentials for virtual Ceneter 2.5 database ? We used MS SQL 2005 server . May be there are configuration file for virtual Center database : IP , dsn , port , username ,password .

Thank's

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're unclear what you want here but whether you're looking for a plain-text userID/password file for either VC, SQL, local or domain Windows accounts you won't find them, they're all hashed away securely.

Why not tell us the actual problem you have and we'll see if there's a more direct solution.